# Eclipse: Cross Compiling using shared library. Linker error "cannot find -lMyProject"

Tags: eclipse, linker, cross-compiling

So I am compiling for MIPS architecture on a Linux 386 host in eclipse CDT. I have a project that is supposed to give me a library I can use on another project. 
Compiling of that project works just fine. I end up with a `libMyProject` file. 
So in my second project I reference the library file with the `-L` option for the path and the `-l` option for the library. All names are correct, however I end up with a Linker error (file not found).
Thats invoking the linker:

```
mips-openwrt-linux-g++ -L"/home/user/workspace/MyProject/DebugLibrary" -o "MySecondProject"  ./HelloWorld.o   -lMyProject
```

And thats the error I get in eclipse:

```
/home/user/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -lMyProject
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it.
Had to append the extension `.a` to the library in the command line pattern of the linker:

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT}.a ${INPUTS}
```